# Group list of objects/AR relation by user_id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of objects which is actually AR Relation. My object has these fields :

```
{
  agreement_id: 1,
  app_user_id: 1,
  agency_name: 'Small business 1'
  ..etc..
},
{
  agreement_id: 2,
  app_user_id: 1,
  agency_name: 'Small business 2'
  ..etc..
}
```

I m representing my object as a Hash for easier understanding. I need to map my list of objects to format like this :

```
{
  1 => [1,2]
}
```

This represents a list of agreement_ids grouped by the user. I always know which user I m grouping on. Here is what I've tried so far :

```
where(app_user_id: user_id).where('...').select('app_user_id, agreement_id').group_by(&:app_user_id)
```

This gives me the structure what I want but not exactly the data that I want, here is an output of this :

```
{1=>
  [#<Agreement:0x6340fdbb agreement_id: 1, app_user_id: 1>,
   #<Agreement:0x91bd4dd agreement_id: 2, app_user_id: 1>]
 }
```

I've also thought I was going to be able to do this with `map` method, and here is what I tried :

```
where(app_user_id: user_id).where('....').select('app_user_id, agreement_id').map do |ag|
  { ag.app_user_id => ag.agreement_id } 
end.reduce(&:merge)
```

But it only produces the mapping with the last agreement_id like this :

```
{1=>2}
```

I've tried some other things not worth mentioning. Can anyone suggest a way that would make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work :

```
where(app_user_id: user_id)
  .where('...')
  .select('app_user_id, agreement_id')
  .group_by(&:app_user_id).map{|k,v| Hash[k, v.map(&:agreement_id)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
where(app_user_id: user_id).
  where('...').
  select('app_user_id, agreement_id').
  map { |a| [a.app_user_id, a.agreement_id] }.
  group_by(&:first)
```